# How older version of android before 4.0 store data like password, accesstoken securly?

Tags: java, android, security, mobile, android-keystore

I am building an android application that needs to store secure data on android device which also support older version of android before 4.0. I know that android 4.0 and version after that support key chain but my application needs to support older version.
So can any one help and let me know which method used in older os version of Android.

Comment: For some good reading, see [See Unifying Key Store Access in ICS](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/03/unifying-key-store-access-in-ics.html) and [Using the ICS KeyChain API](http://nelenkov.blogspot.com/2011/11/using-ics-keychain-api.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Android versions previous to ICS you can use `KeyStore`, here is an example of storing to `KeyStore`:

```
public boolean setEntry(String alias, String secretKey) {

    boolean keyStoreEntryWritten = false;

    if (mKeystore != null && secretKey != null) {
        // store something in the key store
        SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getBytes(), "MD5");
        KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry ske = new KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry(sks);
        KeyStore.ProtectionParameter pp = new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(null);

        try {
            mKeystore.setEntry(alias, ske, pp);

            // save key store
            boolean success = saveKeyStore();

            if (success) {
                keyStoreEntryWritten = true;
            }
        } catch (KeyStoreException ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to read keystore" + mKeyStoreName);
        }
    }
    return keyStoreEntryWritten;
}


private boolean saveKeyStore() {

    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    boolean keyStoreSaved = true;

    // generate key store path
    String keyStoreFilePath = generateKeyStoreFilePath(mKeyStoreName, mKeystoreDirectoryPath);


    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(keyStoreFilePath);
        mKeystore.store(fos, mKeyStorePassword.toCharArray());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        keyStoreSaved = false;
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to save keystore " + mKeyStoreName);
    } finally {
        if (fos != null) {
            try {
                fos.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                keyStoreSaved = false;
                Log.e(TAG, "Failed to close FileOutputStream");
            }
        }
    }
    return keyStoreSaved;
}
```

You can find some more info here: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/KeyStore.html

**EDIT:** 
Here is how you retrieve a key:

```
public String getEntry(String alias) {

    String secretStr = null;
    byte[] secret = null;

    if (mKeystore != null) {



        try {
            if (!mKeystore.containsAlias(alias)) {
                Log.w(TAG, new StringBuilder().append("Keystore ").append(mKeyStoreName)
                        .append(" does not contain entry ").append(alias).toString());
                return null;
            }
        } catch (KeyStoreException ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to read keystore entry " + alias);
        }

        // get my entry from the key store
        KeyStore.ProtectionParameter pp = new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(null);
        KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry ske = null;
        try {
            ske = (KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry) mKeystore.getEntry(alias, pp);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to read keystore entry " + alias);
        }

        if (ske != null) {
            SecretKeySpec sks = (SecretKeySpec) ske.getSecretKey();
            secret = sks.getEncoded();

            if (secret != null) {
                secretStr = new String(secret);


            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, new StringBuilder().append("Read empty keystore entry ").append(alias).toString());
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to read keystore entry " + alias);
        }
    }
    return secretStr;
}
```

Comment: Thanks inistel. Its really useful but now my concern is I have to store secretKey somewhere right and so again the question arise that how to store it securely? correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I added an example of fetching back the key - hope this helps

Comment: Once again thanks inistel. After looking at code, still I have concern about the mKeyStorePassword. Is that secure I mean as I understand it can be access and there is no security for it right? correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You can set the password in your code (hard coded) so it can not be accessed, or, you can encrypt it and store in any other way. The KeyStore will help you with saving secured data which is dynamic.

Comment: "You can set the password in your code (hard coded) so it can not be accessed..." - hard coding a password in a program violates a number of secure coding practices.

Comment: One option (not the ultimate) is to store the secret in the native code, sufficiently obfuscated so that reading the SO library via object dump and HEX editor is overly complex and deters most hackers. Additionally, the native code for reading the secret can implement caller context check to ensure only your java app can read the secret and no else reads, loads and use the shared lib. For best solution though, the secret must be stored on the Android keystore that only your app can access to (may require dynamic exchange of secrets between your app and a trusted server).